# Dropbox API /save_url set custom headers for Dropbox to use when requesting the file from url

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api

When using the /save_url API method, Does anyone know how I can configure custom headers for dropbox to set when its services attempt to download a file from the specified url to the dropbox folder.

I am basically trying to set an Authorisation: Bearer {token} header so that dropbox has access to a file that is accessible via url but only with the bearer token set in the header of the GET request.

Just to be clear, I am not asking how to set the Dropbox Bearer Token to make an API request to Dropbox... this is for configuring that request to do the same on their end when requesting the file.

I am referring to this documentation on dropbox's website:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#save-url

Thanks in advance, I am not expecting this to be possible but I am hopeful.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox /save_url functionality doesn't offer a way to set headers like this, or otherwise attach authentication information. We'll consider it a feature request though.

That being the case, if you control the resource host, as a workaround you can instead generate URLs that contain random, unguessable tokens, and/or that are time-limited which you would then supply to Dropbox.